# Excel Visualbasic Move Part of Row to second row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to move part of a row in excel to a new row just below the original row.  I found a way to insert a blank row between all rows of data but cannot figure out how to cut the data from cells AG:AR to the row below in A:L.  There could be unlimited number of rows.

Here a sample of what I have and what I want it to look like when it is finished:

Sample Start Data:

```
Row 1: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5 A6 A7 A8

Row 2: B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 B6 B7 B8
```

Finished Product:

```
Row 1: A1 A2 A3 A4 A5

Row 2: A6 A7 A8

Row 3: B1 B2 B3 B4 B5 

Row 4: B6 B7 B8
```

I was able to figure it out with the below:

I was able to figure it out.

Here is what I did:

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim NextRow As Long

 Do Until ActiveCell.Row = 2
    LastRow = Range("AG65536").End(xlUp).Row
    NextRow = Range("AG65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("AG" & LastRow & ":AR" & LastRow).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A" & NextRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("AG2:AR2")
rng.Cut Destination:= rng.offset(1,0).Entirerow.Cells(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This would work as well with a few modifications.